# Conditional CDF of Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$X_t$ and $Y_t$ are poisson processes with rates $a$ and $b$ (independent processes)

$n = 1,2,3...$

Find the conditional CDF $F_X{}_t{}_|{}_X{}_t{}_+{}_Y{}_t{}_={}_n(x)$

I get an answer of something along the lines of $1-\frac{e^{-at}\Big( \sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{(at)^k}{k!} \Big)}{e^{-(a+b)t}\frac{((a+b)t)^n}{n!}}$ which doesn't look right

Comment: You just silently cancelled the condition that X and Y are *independent processes*. Please **do not do that** (and restore the question to its version when people answered it).

Answer (score 3):

At time $t$, both $X_t\sim \mathrm{po}(at)$ and $Y_t\sim \mathrm{po}(bt)$, so it suffices to find the conditional distribution of $$X\mid X+Y,$$where $X\sim\mathrm{po}(\lambda_1)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{po}(\lambda_2)$ are independent Poisson distributed variables.

This is easiest done in terms of the probability function: Let $n\geq 1$, then for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X=k\mid X+Y=n)&=\frac{P(X=k,X+Y=n)}{P(X+Y=n)}=\frac{P(X=k,Y=n-k)}{P(X+Y=n)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\lambda_1^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda_1}\frac{\lambda_2^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}e^{-\lambda_2}}{\frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^n}{n!}e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}},
\end{align*}
$$
where we have used that $X+Y\sim\mathrm{po}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. By simplifying this we see that
$$
P(X=k\mid X+Y=n)=\binom{n}{k}\lambda^k(1-\lambda)^{n-k},\quad k=0,1,\ldots,n
$$
where
$$
\lambda=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.
$$

In other words, $X\mid X+Y=n\sim\mathrm{bin}(n,\lambda)$. Now you can find the CDF of $X\mid X+Y=n$ by summing these probabilities.

Comment: So, the summation from m=0 to m=k?

Comment: Yes, summing from $m=0$ to $m=k$ will give you the CDF evaluated at $k$, i.e. $P(X\leq k\mid X+Y=n)$.